# Link with image on one line

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, html-table

Can someone help me to bring the arrows and the text on one line? (see image) The link tag should fill out the "th" (display:block).

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<th colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="ui-state-default">
<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s"></span>
</th>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(../images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); }
.ui-icon-carat-2-n-s { background-position: -128px 0; }

table#example th a {
   display:block;
}

table#example th span {
   float: right;
}
```

Can I may be realize that with the z-index CSS-attribute or something like that?

Comment: You're missing an ending > on the span and a closing </a>.. Is that a typo or from your real code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding float left to the anchor:

```
table#example th a {
   float: left;
   display:block;
}
```

Comment: With `float: left` the link doesn't fill out the whole "th".

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS so that the `<a>` and `<span>` both float left:

```
table#example th a {
    float: left;
}

table#example th span {
    float: left;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/nYHcW/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to be using tables for this? If you're using tables purely for layout; don't. There's a few ways to do this using css:

**Method 1:**

HTML

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
<span class="arrows"></span>
```

CSS

```
.link, .arrows  {
  float: left;
}

.link {
  margin: 0px 10px; /* Spacing either side of link */
}
```

**Method 2**

HTML

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
<span class="arrows"></span>
```

CSS

```
.link {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0px 10px; /* Spacing either side of link */
}
```